# rails eager load search data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include

I hava 2 models here:

```
School(foreign_id), User(name)
```

and School model:

```
belongs_to :developer,foreign_key: 'developer_id',class_name:"User"


belongs_to :manager,foreign_key: 'manager_id',class_name:"User"


belongs_to :guesst,foreign_key: 'guesst_id',class_name:"User"
```

now ,i want to search School by guessts.name or manager's name .

```
School.eager_load(:guesst,manager...).where({my_condition})
```

i have tried :

```
{guessts:{name:somename}}
```

but error happened ,how to fix this? ty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does this look?

```
User.where(name: 'Layne Staley').includes(:schools).first
```

Comment: i knew it now: School.eager_load(:guesst,manager...).where({managers_agents:{id..,name... }  }) ,rails auto generate sql as its rule. ,but really ty.